# How can I query individuals which are reasoned from a class with sparql wh

Tags: sparql, owl, protege, reasoning, hermit

I have started the Fact++ reasoner in Protege and now I want to query the reasoned individuals from this class C.

```
SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x rdf:type  ex:C.}
```

This query does not give any result. Can I query rasoned content from sparql in Protege or does SPARQL just work on the original content without considering reasoned interactions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to use the Snap SPARQL plugin for reasoning awareness with SPARQL